# Super algebraic decaying series

Tags: integration, inequality, summation

For $a>0$, $b > 1$ and $c \geq 1$ it holds
$$F(a,b,c):=\sum_{j=a+1}^\infty \exp(-b \log(j)^c) \leq \int_{a}^\infty \exp(-b \log(x)^c) \, d x < \infty.$$
I am looking for upper bounds on $F$. For example, if $c=1$, the integral can be evaluated in closed form and we obtain
$$F(a,b,1) \leq \frac{a^{1-b}}{b-1} .$$

However, for $c>1$ the integral does not have a closed-form. So is there anything known on either the integral or $F$ itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a change of variable in the integral $(y=(log(x)^c))$ to make terms reminding of the Gamma function appear. More specifically, you get a $e^{y^{(1/c)}}$ which you can majorate by $e^y$: you will see it if you try. Another linear variable change will get you an integral in the form of the rest of a Gamma function.
A rough upper bound is hence: $(\frac 1c)(\frac{1}{(b-1)})^{1/c}\Gamma (\frac 1c)$